# Pandas `.assign` to multiple columns from single function

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Pandas dataframe which contains a single column `val`, as well as a function `func` which takes in a value and spits out a list of some fixed length (let's say 4). I also have a list `cols` of 4 strings. I would like to apply func to every cell and add 4 new columns, labelled according to my list.

What seems to work is something like this:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'val': [1, 2, 4, 18, 9, 1]})
cols = ["X", "Y", "Z", "hello"]
func = lambda x: [2**x, str(x), x+1, "world"]

df[cols] = df['val'].apply(lambda val: pd.Series(func(val)))
```

Since I see everyone recommend against using `apply` I wanted to try and do it with `assign`. I tried assigning the output of `func` to a temporary column `tmp`, and then extract the individual values one by one as follows:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'val': [1, 2, 4, 18, 9, 1]})
cols = ["X", "Y", "Z", "hello"]
func = lambda x: [2**x, str(x), x+1, "world"]

kwargs = {name: (lambda x: x.tmp[idx]) for idx, name in enumerate(cols)}
df[cols] = df.assign(tmp=lambda x: pd.Series(func(x.val)), **kwargs)
```

But this throws some kind of error that I'm not sure how to interpret `ValueError: Columns must be same length as key`. Note that the documentation for `.assign` [1] says that this kind of self-reference is allowed, see the last example.

[1] https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html

EDIT: For the sake of clarification, in my actual application the call to `func` is sufficiently expensive that I don't want to call it four times per row. It's also not easily separable into four subcomponents like in my example.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the key is you need to use a lambda function to apply to the input column, specifying the `result_type='expand'` option and the axis. Then you can define any number of output columns to which to assign the results.

Here's a simple example I created with one input column and two output columns, in a gist: https://gist.github.com/84adam/29ff5fd1286a30d904540bf78e37f883

Example syntax:

`df[['output1','output2']] = df.apply(lambda x: func(x['input1']), axis=1, result_type='expand')`

I think that should do the trick.

Comment: This worked for me in my similar problem that I was researching, OP apparently didn't bother to try the solution. You should be awarded the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'val': [1, 2, 4, 18, 9, 1]})
cols = ["X", "Y", "Z", "hello"]
func = lambda x: [2**x, str(x), x+1, "world"]

df[cols] = df['val'].apply(lambda val: pd.Series(func(val)), result_type='expand')
```

I think the addition of `expand` will give the correct result.

Update:

Using `assign`:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'val': [1, 2, 4, 18, 9, 1]})
cols = ["X", "Y", "Z", "hello"]
func1 = lambda x: 2**x
func2 = lambda x: str(x)
func3 = lambda x: x+1
func4 = lambda x: "world"

df.assign(X=lambda x: pd.Series(func1(x['val'])),
            Y=df['val'].astype(str),
            Z=lambda x: pd.Series(func3(x['val'])),
            hello='world',
            )
```

Output:

```
    val X   Y   Z   hello
0   1   2   1   2   world
1   2   4   2   3   world
2   4   16  4   5   world
3   18  262144  18  19  world
4   9   512 9   10  world
5   1   2   1   2   world
```

Comment: Without that result_type it also gives the correct result, the question is how to do it with `assign`.

Comment: @TimonKnigge I've updated the answer using `assign`

Answer (score 0):

Whenver you use a lambda in a list comprehension, [you probably wanted to use](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fZE6ZWde-Os) `functools.partial`

```py
import pandas as pd
import functools

df = pd.DataFrame({"val": [1, 2, 4, 18, 9, 1]})
cols = ["X", "Y", "Z", "hello"]
func = lambda x: [2**x, str(x), x + 1, "world"]


def slice_list(df, col, idx):
    return [item[idx] for item in df[col]]


slicer = lambda idx: functools.partial(slice_list, col="tmp", idx=idx)

kwargs = {name: slicer(idx) for idx, name in enumerate(cols)}

new_df = df.assign(tmp=lambda x: pd.Series(x.val.apply(func)), **kwargs).drop(
    columns=["tmp"]
)

print(new_df)
```

```
   val       X   Y   Z  hello
0    1       2   1   2  world
1    2       4   2   3  world
2    4      16   4   5  world
3   18  262144  18  19  world
4    9     512   9  10  world
5    1       2   1   2  world
```

Answer (score -1):

You'd have to do some testing to see if the original func is more performant over the assign method below.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'val': [1, 2, 4, 18, 9, 1]})
df = df.assign(X=2**df['val'],
               Z=df['val']+1,
               Y=df['val'].astype('str'),
               world='hello')

   val       X   Z   Y  world
0    1       2   2   1  hello
1    2       4   3   2  hello
2    4      16   5   4  hello
3   18  262144  19  18  hello
4    9     512  10   9  hello
5    1       2   2   1  hello
```

Comment: The point is that there is a single function which returns a list, this one was just as an example. The real one can not be broken up like this.